# ffmpeg reading from pipe to pipe doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I'm trying to read audio data from one stream to other passing it through ffmpeg process.

```
Process? CreateStream()
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"sources\ffmpeg",
        Arguments = @"-hide_banner -i pipe:0 -f mp3 pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    });
}
```

For this i use OutputDataReceived event:

```
private void Ffmpeg_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Data);

        //writing data to another stream
    }
}
```

But it falls at the end (even if i only getting data from input stream standart output without writing it it to output stream) with:

> Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:0':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : google/video-file
> Duration: 00:03:13.12, start: -0.007000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
> Stream mapping:
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
> Output #0, mp3, to 'pipe:1':
> Metadata:
> TSSE            : Lavf59.27.100
> Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libmp3lame
> size=    2969kB time=00:03:09.99 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=47.5x

> av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
> Last message repeated 4 times

> Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Invalid argument
> size=    2997kB time=00:03:11.91 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=47.4x
> video:0kB audio:2999kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

> Error closing file pipe:1: Invalid argument
> Conversion failed!

It works well when i reading data from stream to file, what means that input data is valid:

```
Arguments = @"-hide_banner -i pipe:0 -f mp3 output.mp3"
```

main function code (it is the same for all examples):

```
async Task Do() 
{
    using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream())
    {
        if (ffmpeg == null) return;

        ffmpeg.OutputDataReceived += Ffmpeg_OutputDataReceived;

        using (var audioStream = GetInputStream())
        {
            ffmpeg.BeginOutputReadLine();
            await audioStream.CopyToAsync(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            ffmpeg.StandardInput.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think bropblem because you read output as text
Try

```
using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream())
{
    if (ffmpeg == null) return;
    using (var audioStream = GetInputStream())
    {
        await audioStream.CopyToAsync(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
        ffmpeg.StandardInput.Close();
    }
    using (var audioStream = GetOuputStream())
    {
        await ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(audioStream);
    }
}
```